# Post request in flutter giving error but still pushing the object created

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi im trying to post some data to my backend and when im pushing the data an error is catched that says failed to create expense based on the **Create expense method**.

Eventhough it gives me that error that certain expense it is added on the list of expenses.

Also I dont know if im doing it right because i want to input an integer to the amount field but im converting it into a string.
And in the button section im using int.parse() for the amount value.
Maybe is this causing the issue ?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:fin_app/models/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Expenses> createExpense(String category,int amount,String date,String paymentType) async {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse('****************'),
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'category': category,
        'amount': amount.toString(),
        'date': date,
        'paymentType': paymentType
    }),
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 201) {
    // If the server did return a 201 CREATED response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Expenses.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 201 CREATED response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to create expense.');
  }
}



void main() {
  runApp(const InputTest());
}

class InputTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const InputTest({super.key});

  @override
  State<InputTest> createState() {
    return _InputTestState();
  }
}

class _InputTestState extends State<InputTest> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _dateInput = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _amountInput = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _typeInput = TextEditingController();
  Future<Expenses>? _futureExpense;

    @override
  void initState() {
    _dateInput.text = ""; //set the initial value of text field
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
       
        body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: (_futureExpense == null) ? buildColumn() : buildFutureBuilder(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Column buildColumn() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(
          controller: _controller,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Title'),
        ),
        TextField(
                controller: _dateInput, //editing controller of this TextField
                decoration: InputDecoration( 
                   icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today), //icon of text field
                   labelText: "Enter Date" //label text of field
                ),
                readOnly: true,  //set it true, so that user will not able to edit text
                onTap: () async {
                  DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
                      context: context, initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                      firstDate: DateTime(2000), //DateTime.now() - not to allow to choose before today.
                      lastDate: DateTime(2101)
                  );
                  
                  if(pickedDate != null ){
                      print(pickedDate);  //pickedDate output format => 2021-03-10 00:00:00.000
                      String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(pickedDate); 
                      print(formattedDate); //formatted date output using intl package =>  2021-03-16
                        //you can implement different kind of Date Format here according to your requirement

                      setState(() {
                         _dateInput.text = formattedDate; //set output date to TextField value. 
                      });
                  }else{
                      print("Date is not selected");
                  }
                },
             ),
        TextField(
          controller: _amountInput,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter amount'),
        ),
        TextField(
          controller: _typeInput,
          decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter paymentType'),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _futureExpense = createExpense(_controller.text,int.parse(_amountInput.text),_dateInput.text,_typeInput.text);
            });
          },
          child: const Text('Create Data'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  FutureBuilder<Expenses> buildFutureBuilder() {
    return FutureBuilder<Expenses>(
      future: _futureExpense,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text(snapshot.data!.category!);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
        }

        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: problem is in your backend code part.

Answer (score 0):

the main reason is that your conversion :

```
 jsonEncode(<String, String>{
    'category': category,
    'amount': amount.toString(),
    'date': date,
    'paymentType': paymentType
}),
```

> this is wrong. here you convert the value jsonstring but you server accept a amount a integer or float.
> you can try this way.

```
 jsonEncode({
    'category': category,
    'amount': amount.toString(),
    'date': date,
    'paymentType': paymentType
}),
```

I hope you problem is sloved